# Using aptana.log without switching to debug perspective?

Tags: javascript, debugging, aptana

I want to use aptana.log to write messages in aptana console view without having to switch to debug view which launch external browser (Firefox), I already have console.log in Firefox, I want to log messages in aptana console without launching external browser.

Answer (score 1):

Please review: [Using the Console View - Aptana](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Using_the_Console_View)

Specifically the statement:

> You will need to have the debugger set up to run to use the Console View. See Running the debugger for help.

Answer (score 1):

In Aptana Studio (2.0 or 3.0), open "Run Configurations", select your Web Browser configuration. Or click on the launch configuration from toolbar Run action with Command key pressed (on Mac, Control on Windows). Then open Advanced tab and check "Enable logging in run mode".

Cheers,
Max